# What should we do with this question?

Tags: discussion, migration, unanswered-questions

Should we migrate This question: ([After Effects: Bend and animate along path](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/79245/63979)) to [Video Production beta](https://video.stackexchange.com/)?

Should we delete/archive it?

It's been asked on our site almost 1.5yr ago and hasn't gotten **any** answers. (Because it really doesn't fall under our expertise) however, I believe it will get much better attention there, and it would be nice to remove some (hihg voted) questions from our [Unanswered List](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/unanswered)

I'd appreciate input/feedback/opinions regarding this.

---

I know it's too old to migrate, can we manually migrate it?

---

### Update

[From a Mod there in chat:](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41899533#41899533)
"it should be on topic from what I can tell
we handle a lot of ae stuff though I'm not sure if anyone will be familiar with that particular random plugin"

Answer (score 4):

We do not migrate things that are on topic here. It has 6 upvotes, no downvotes, or close votes. Just because it hasn't been answered isn't grounds for removal.

A lesser point is that Video is in Beta and its generally not advised to migrate things to beta sites as there's no guarantee that it will survive. If it was completely off topic everywhere but the beta site than it can be done but on fringe cases its usually best not to.

I work in animation from time to time but simply have no experience with that particular plugin or I would've tried to answer it myself.

Answer (score 1):

It's too old to migrate.  Think the timeframe is less than 6 months a questions should be moved:

[image]

From my understanding it's somewhat frowned upon to move questions that can be answered and are in scope on a graduated site to a beta site.

Comment: I know it's too old to migrate, can (it be) manually migrate(d)

Comment: That's just it, I **think** it's highly frowned upon.  Courtesy would also be to go to that site's chatroom and ask if it's ok.